# SSMS: Show execution plan for a stored procedure as a single tree

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I execute a stored procedure with an option "Include Actual Execution Plan". The execution plan always is represented by multiple statements each of which has its own execution plan.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) states the following:

> If the statement is a stored procedure
>   or Transact-SQL statement, it becomes
>   the root of the graphical execution
>   plan tree structure. The stored
>   procedure can have multiple children
>   that represent statements called by
>   the stored procedure. Each child is a
>   node or branch of the tree.

In this case I expect to run a stored procedure and see only one tree where the root node is the stored procedure.

How it is possible to switch on such plan visualization for a stored procedure?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like *an estimated subtree cost* is not the same for *actual* and *estimated* execution plans.

Is there a way how one can see Estimated execution cost for the whole stored procedure and not only for its statements?

Comment: @gbn: added the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Estimated plans (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) show a tree structure. Actual plans (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) do not.

I've never seen a tree for a procedure in an actual plan (and I never use estimated plans anyway)

Comment: @gbn: sounds dissapointing....

Comment: @gbn: the reason why I want to have that is to see "Estimated query subtree cost" of a procedure execution: ToolTip on the left most operator shows this. Do you probably know some other methods?

Comment: You will see this for Estimated plans

Comment: Ok, that's the answer and +1.

Comment: @Martin: As I understand Estimated subtree cost is exactly the number which optimizer looks at in order to choose the plan. For which constructs they are inaccurate?

Comment: @gbn: I looks I was too fast with the answer. In fact, Estimate Subtree cost are not the same for Actual execution plan and estimated execution plan :-( Are there some suggestions?

Comment: @Tim: As I said, I never use estimated plans because I find them useless.

Comment: @gbn: please don't be offended because I put away the solution tag from this answer. I believe that the correct answer would help for those who have the same question in the future and for me as well.

Comment: @gbn: no worries. I *really* don't use them though. I have tables with a billion rows+ and I want to know how my code *really* runs :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way how one can see
>   Estimated execution cost for the whole
>   stored procedure and not only for its
>   statements?

The only way I think you can do this is by capturing the `XML` plans and inspecting these (aggregating the value for the individual plans). Capturing these plans is only possible by a trace as far as I know so you could create a couple of helper stored procedures to manage the setup and termination of the trace and sandwich your actual stored procedure call inbetween.

```
DECLARE @TraceID INT
EXEC StartCapture @@SPID, @TraceID OUTPUT
EXEC sp_help 'sys.objects' /*<-- Call your stored proc of interest here.*/
EXEC StopCapture @TraceID
```

### Example `StartCapture` Definition

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StartCapture
@Spid INT,
@TraceID INT OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @maxfilesize BIGINT = 5
DECLARE @filepath NVARCHAR(200) = N'C:\trace_' + LEFT(NEWID(),36)

EXEC sp_trace_create @TraceID OUTPUT, 0, @filepath, @maxfilesize, NULL 

exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 1, 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 22, 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 34, 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 51, 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 122, 12, 1
-- filter for spid
EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 12, 0, 0, @Spid
-- start the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1
```

### Example `StopCapture` Definition

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE StopCapture
@TraceID INT
AS
WITH  XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' as sql), 
      CTE
     as (SELECT CAST(TextData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TextData,
                ObjectID,
                ObjectName,
                EventSequence,
                /*costs accumulate up the tree so the MAX should be the root*/
                MAX(EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost) AS EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost
         FROM   fn_trace_getinfo(@TraceID) fn
                CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(200)), 1)
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(TextData AS XML) AS xPlan) x
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.relop.value('@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost',
                                            'float') AS EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost
                             FROM   xPlan.nodes('//sql:RelOp') T(relop)) ca
         WHERE  property = 2
                AND TextData IS NOT NULL
                AND ObjectName not in ( 'StopCapture', 'fn_trace_getinfo' )
         GROUP  BY CAST(TextData AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
                   ObjectID,
                   ObjectName,
                   EventSequence)
SELECT ObjectName,
       SUM(EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost) AS EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost
FROM   CTE
GROUP  BY ObjectID,
          ObjectName  

-- Stop the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0
-- Close and delete the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2
GO
```